# Displaying taxonomies with manage_{custom-post-type}_posts_custom_column

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

How to display taxonomies column for a custom post type while using `manage_{custom-post-type}_posts_custom_column` filter?

I tried:

```
if( 'sections' == $column ) {
 echo get_the_term_list($post->ID,'sections');
}
```

But it creates links to the taxonomy archive page, I want it to filter results in the edit.php page by this taxonomy (the default case).

Answer (score 0):

Solved it just by using `taxonomy-{taxonomy-name}` in an array in the filter `manage_{post-type}_posts_columns`